# my iframe tag code is not working in localhost

Tags: php, html, mysql

I wrote 2 iframe tags code like below using google docs viewver,

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/mypdf.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

---

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=C%3A%5Cxampp%5Chtdocs%5CJeywin%20Tech%5COasis%20HR%5Cresource%5Cupload%5Cresumes%5C1406262263_resume%20php_tutorial.pdf&embedded=true" width="820" height="700" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Here the first one file is viewing perfectly because its from online...The second one file shows the error that below and its from localhost folder,

Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists.
You can also try to download the original document by clicking here.

Comment: Google Docs cant access your local documents.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9617/how-do-i-get-local-documents-to-directly-open-in-google-docs

Comment: set the localpath as src.

Comment: Thank You Darren...Then, is there any other code to display pdf,docx,doc files in php form in localhost and online?